# External CSS Styles not being affected on website

Tags: html, css

I have developed my website which consist `index.html` and CSS file name is `main.css`. I have tried to import the external style sheet in to my current `index.html` by using following tag.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
```

Screen shot is here[image: Live Screen shot]
But I have problem that is what are the styles are in the `CSS` file those styles are not being effected on my website. But when I tried to use is in `codepen` it is working perfectly.

Try to see Live demo:[CodePen code](https://codepen.io/RamBM/pen/mpomRv)

If have any doubt try to execute in your local machine by separating `html` file and `css`   file

why it is working on `index.html`?

**Edit:** File Structure

[image: File Structure]

Comment: Is your css file inside a folder css? if not the script is:
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">

Comment: It is under css file only

Comment: change the script to what i wrote. if your html and css files are in the same place it should work
<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: Please, show us your folder structure

Comment: @SergioTx I have updated my question with file structure. Please see it

Comment: Have you checked the website by using incognito mode in your browser? Could be that your cache is still showing the old website.

Comment: @Granny yeah I have tried still no use

Comment: I see you have 2 `index.html` opened, maybe it's not the correct one, it happens to me sometimes when have files with same name opened

Comment: use a path relative to the root: `href="/css/main.css"` (note the leading slash)